# vuex error with quasar $store.auth is undefined

Tags: vuex, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to use vuex with Quasar. I have created an authentication module as below.

```
// src/store/auth/index.js
import { api } from 'boot/axios';

export default {
    state: {
      user: null,
    },
    getters: {
      isAuthenticated: state => !!state.user,
      StateUser: state => state.user,
    },
    mutations: {
      setUser(state, username){
        state.user = username
      },
      LogOut(state){
        state.user = null
      },
    },
    actions: {
        LOGIN: ({ commit }, payload) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              api
                .post(`/api/login`, payload)
                .then(({ data, status }) => {
                  if (status === 200) {
                    commit('setUser', data.refresh_token)
                    resolve(true);
                  }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  reject(error);
                });
            });
        },
    }
}
```

I imported it in the store

```
// src/store/index.js
import { store } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import auth from './auth'

export default store(function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = createStore({
    modules: {
      auth:auth
    },

    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode and --debug builds only
    strict: process.env.DEBUGGING
  })

  return Store
})
```

And I imported it into MainLayout to check if the user is logged in.

```
// src/layouts/MainLayout
<template>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import packageInfo from '../../package.json'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'MainLayout',
  setup () {
    const $store = useStore;
    const connected = ref(false);

    function checkLogin(){
      //console.log($store)
      return connected.value = $store.auth.isAuthenticated
    };

    onMounted(()=> {
      checkLogin();
    });

    return {
      appName: packageInfo.productName,
      link:ref('dashboard'),
      drawer: ref(false),
      miniState: ref(true),
      checkLogin,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But every time, I get the same error :

> $store.auth is undefined

I tried to follow the quasar documentation, but I can't. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me to find the solution. My error is to have written `const $store = useStore` instead of `const $store = useStore()`. Thanks